# Acumatica - Mail goes to Junk

Tags: office365, acumatica

We are sending invoices to our customers using Acumatica ERP but those mails go into recipient's junk folders. We relay the message through Office 365 and apparently, it's getting delivered through High Probability of Spam IP.

From Acumatica's POV, is there way for us to get out of bad IP pool of Office?

```
Received: from PX.Common.Mail.SmtpSender (2603:10c6:1:14::27) by
 SYCPR01MB4351.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com (2603:10c6:10:42::19) with Microsoft
 SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id
 15.20.2305.17 via Mailbox Transport; Fri, 4 Oct 2019 04:40:15 +0000
From: &quot;EMAIL&quot; &lt;EMAIL@SENDERDOMAIN.CO.NZ&gt;
To: EMAIL@RECIPIENTDOMAIN.CO.NZ
Reply-To: &quot;EMAIL&quot; &lt;EMAIL@SENDERDOMAIN.CO.NZ&gt;
Subject: INVOICE #000265xx92
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=dbc2212c_6721_4f52_ae57_2438f2ac3435
Message-ID: &lt;6933e623-20f1-4c3f-a1f0-6bd9212106aa_acumatica@smtp.office365.com&gt;
Date: Fri, 04 Oct 2019 04:40:15 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTime: 04 Oct 2019 04:40:15.5620
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationStartTimeReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationInterval: 1:00:00:00.0000000
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-ExpirationIntervalReason: OriginalSubmit
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-Network-Message-Id:
0586eb59-2473-4b62-6338-08d74884f393
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: SYCPR01MB4351.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 06
X-Originating-IP: [13.54.62.140]
X-ClientProxiedBy: SY2PR01CA0015.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10c6:1:14::27) To SYCPR01MB4351.ausprd01.prod.outlook.com
 (2603:10c6:10:42::19)
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-MessageDirectionality: Originating
Return-Path: EMAIL@SENDERDOMAIN.CO.NZ
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. It was due to tremendous embedded links to advertising networks. No wonder why mails were being flagged as spam.

Folks, check the source code! Not sure why this ERP does this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things you can look into

If it all the mail giving an issue, then it mostly Acumatica. An embedded link or subject line that is funny;

If it is some mailboxes moving it to the spam folder, it may be your mailbox or email address. This can be because the mailbox was used for spam

Try this link:
https://optinmonster.com/11-reasons-why-your-emails-go-in-the-spam-box-and-how-to-make-sure-they-dont/

Comment: The subject line could be considered funny: "Subject: INVOICE #000265xx92" All caps should be avoided and invoice is a sensitive word when sent alongside attachment.

Comment: I have opened a support case with Acumatica a few months ago (#106290) regarding the same issue. According to the support engineer nobody else has reported a similar issue. We were trying to use Mailgun or Sendgrid to get delivery/open data with one of the customizations that we developed and I gave up and went back to using our GMail SMTP server. Here's a few things that I flagged up in the support case:

Comment: From my support case: "E-mails sent from Acumatica frequently get flagged as SPAM, even after configuring SPF/DKIM and other DNS settings to improve deliverability. Upon further analysis by https://www.mail-tester.com and http://isnotspam.com there is an issue that could be affecting deliverability.

The MIME headers are missing from the e-mail message and are required as per RFC 2045. Apache SpamAssassin says that "This suggests that the message was generated by a badly-written mailout program rather than by a normal email client.".

Comment: Also, the plain text representation of the message is missing.

Comment: Thing is whenever we send invoice directly through email client, it works like a charm. Same content, same subject line etc. Can this be because of how ACUMATICA's relay is setup?